# NIntegration of trace of matrix, which was obtained by NDSolve, converging too slowly

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

e.g.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

H[a1_, a2_, a3_, t_] := {{0, Cos[a1*t], Cos[a2*t]}, {Cos[a1*t], 0, Cos[a3*t]}, {Cos[a2*t], Cos[a3*t], 0}}

Ut[a1_, a2_, a3_] := Ut[a1, a2, a3] = NDSolveValue[{Derivative[1][u][x] == (-I)*H[a1, a2, a3, x] . u[x], u[0] == IdentityMatrix[3]}, u, {x, 0, 2*Pi}]

S[t_] := Piecewise[{{CosIntegral[20.*2.*Pi*Abs[t]] - CosIntegral[0.0001*2.*Pi*Abs[t]], t != 0}, {0, t == 0}}]

Mi[a1_, a2_, a3_] := (1/2)*NIntegrate[Tr[Ut[a1, a2, a3][2*Pi] . ConjugateTranspose[Ut[a1, a2, a3][t1]] . {{0, 1/3, 1/3}, {1/3, 0, 1/3}, {1/3, 1/3, 0}} . Ut[a1, a2, a3][t1] . 
       ConjugateTranspose[Ut[a1, a2, a3][t2]] . {{0, 1/3, 1/3}, {1/3, 0, 1/3}, {1/3, 1/3, 0}} . Ut[a1, a2, a3][t2] . {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1/Sqrt[2], 0}, {0, 0, -(1/Sqrt[2])}}]*S[t1 - t2], 
    {t1, 0, 2*Pi}, {t2, 0, t1}]
```

but `Mi[1,2,3]` warning Numerical integration converging  too slowly.

Could  it be modify?

Comment: Function `ut[1,2,3]`doesn't evaluate. Perhaps the initial conditions should be `u[0] == {1, 1, 1}` ?

Comment: @Ulrich Neumann MatrixForm@H should be removed. Sorry for my input error, question have been edited.

Comment: Perhaps `Method -> "InterpolationPointsSubdivision"` inside `NIntegrate` helps.

Comment: @Ulrich Neumann it outcome 3.78277 - 1.2844 I for Mi[1,2,3], but warning NIntegrate obtained 7.56554 -2.5688 I and 0.000363099 for the integral and error estimates.

Comment: In addition to what has been suggested already, it's worth trying `Ut = ParametricNDSolveValue[{Derivative[1][u][x] == (-I)*
     H[a1, a2, a3, x] . u[x], u[0] == IdentityMatrix[3]}, 
  u, {x, 0, 2*Pi}, {a1, a2, a3}]`. `ParametricNDSolveValue` can do derivatives w.r.t. the parameters and should speed up the numerical solutions of the differential equation.

Comment: @Sjoerd Smit. Tried and they are almost the same. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition of `S[t]` is  numerically problematic because of the condition `t==0` and `t != 0`.

Try a smoothed version `S[t]`  which is continuous near `t==0`:

```
S = Function[{t}, Which[t == 0, Log[20/10^-4], True,CosIntegral[20*2*Pi*t] - CosIntegral[10^-4*2*Pi*t] ] // Evaluate]
```

Evaluation time of the integral can be decreased significantly (factor3) if you integrate inside a region:

```
reg=DiscretizeRegion[ImplicitRegion[{0 <= t1 <= 2 Pi && 0 <= t2 <= t1}, {t1, t2}]]

Mi[a1_, a2_, a3_] := (1/2)*
  NIntegrate[
   Tr[Ut[a1, a2, a3][2*Pi] . 
      ConjugateTranspose[
       Ut[a1, a2, a3][t1]] . {{0, 1/3, 1/3}, {1/3, 0, 1/3}, {1/3, 1/3,
         0}} . Ut[a1, a2, a3][t1] . 
      ConjugateTranspose[
       Ut[a1, a2, a3][t2]] . {{0, 1/3, 1/3}, {1/3, 0, 1/3}, {1/3, 1/3,
         0}} . Ut[a1, a2, a3][
       t2] . {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1/Sqrt[2], 0}, {0, 0, -(1/Sqrt[2])}}]*
    S[t1 - t2], Element[{t1, t2}, reg], 
   Method -> "InterpolationPointsSubdivision"]

Mi[1,2,3]
(*3.78283 - 1.28444 I*)
```

Further improvement (evaluation speed) might be achieved if the integrand is interpolated inside `reg`

```
ipMii[a1_, a2_, a3_, n_ (*number of interpolation points*)] := 
  Block[{t1, t2, ip, 
    reg = ImplicitRegion[{0 <= t1 <= t2 && 0 <= t2 <= t1}, {t1, t2}]},
    ip = FunctionInterpolation[(1/
        2) (Tr[Ut[a1, a2, a3][2*Pi] . 
          ConjugateTranspose[
           Ut[a1, a2, a3][t1]] . {{0, 1/3, 1/3}, {1/3, 0, 1/3}, {1/3, 
            1/3, 0}} . Ut[a1, a2, a3][t1] . 
          ConjugateTranspose[
           Ut[a1, a2, a3][t2]] . {{0, 1/3, 1/3}, {1/3, 0, 1/3}, {1/3, 
            1/3, 0}} . 
          Ut[a1, a2, a3][
           t2] . {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1/Sqrt[2], 0}, {0, 
            0, -(1/Sqrt[2])}}]*S[t1 - t2]), {t1, 0, 2 Pi}, {t2, 0, 
      2 Pi}, InterpolationPoints -> n, InterpolationOrder -> 1]] ;
NIntegrate[ipMii[1, 2, 3, 20][t1, t2], Element[{t1, t2}, reg],Method -> "InterpolationPointsSubdivision"]
(*3.86797 - 1.33425 I*)
```

Comment: WOW! Thank you @Ulrich Neumann for your detailed answer! That's really a lot can learned.

Comment: Mi wroks in my laptop. When I run Mii, however, MMA warns The integrand  has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points. I have tried NIntegrate[ip[t1, t2],  {t1,0,Pi}, {t2,0,Pi}]] and it works.  It would be nice if you can tell me what was wrong when I copied the codes.@Ulrich Neumann

Comment: I didn't understand the messages too, but the result seems to be ok.

Comment: See my modified answer.

Comment: Thumbs-up！Thank you again, @Ulrich Neumann. It is an excellent solution.

Comment: You're welcome!